# C# does altering a returned class object change the original state?

Tags: c#, class

Assume I have the following class structure:

```
public class spaList
{
    private List<customerItemFulfillment> customers;

    public customerItemFulfillment addNewCustomer(
      string customerNumber, string customerName)
    {
        customers.Add(new customerItemFulfillment(customerNumber, customerName));
        return customers[customers.Count - 1];
        //Would running .addItem() on this returned object affect the object in the list?
    }
}

public class customerItemFulfillment
{
    public string customerNumber { get; }
    public string customerName { get; }
    public List<itemFulfillment> fulfillmentItems { get; }

    public void addItem(string itemNumber, double rebateAmount, 
                         double fulfillmentPercent)
    {
        fulfillmentItems.Add(new itemFulfillment(itemNumber, 
                   rebateAmount, fulfillmentPercent));
    }

    public customerItemFulfillment(string customerNumber, string customerName)
    {
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }
}
```

If I did something like:

```
spaList spaListings = new SpaList();
customerItemFulfillment newCustomer = spaListings.addNewCustomer(
                                   "customer name", "customer number");
newCustomer.addItem("item number", 25.00, 8.0);
```

Does that change the `customerItemFulfillment` object in `spaList.customers` or is it just a copy of that object?

ie. would I later be able to do something like - `spaListings.customers[0].fulfillmentItems[0]` and have that be the item that I added earlier?

Comment: Yes. It will change it. Read about reference types and how  they are passed around in C#. Also, why are you asking, when running small sample program will show you that?

Comment: It would have taken you less time to run the code you'd already written and find out for yourself than it took you to write this question.

Comment: @Servy not by my computer and had the code on git, and was curious about my structure / it just didn't feel 100% correct

Comment: @Adjit Then you could have tested it as soon as you got back to your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object is a reference type. That means that the object *reference* is returned from the method, not a copy of the object. So yes, you are changing the original item. If you do this, you might end up with an invalid state of your customers list.

One option is to return a copy of the object. The easiest way to do this is by cloning the class and its properties using an implementation of `ICloneable`.

Comment: Why could this cause an invalid cache state?

Comment: What if your cache assumes it never changes and always remains the original item?